# Multi-thread context switching in register-less machine

Tags: multithreading, turing-machines, context-switch

As I know, multi-thread context switching is pre-emptive initiated by the OS, transparent from the perspective of thread. Generally, when context switching, OS saves all the register values and restores them later switching back to that thread. This includes stack-pointer of that thread.

But consider a hypothetical register-less machine. In this, I can use a fixed address in memory to store the stack-pointer. But here, when the context-switches, stack-pointer is not guaranteed to be preserved. The other thread stores its stack-pointer in the same address. Since it is a global variable, it will corrupt stack-pointer of all other process in the same thread. How to avoid this? How can I store stack-pointers without necessarily needing registers, but also keeping stack-pointer valid after a context-switch?

I'm asking this because, since every computer is equivalent to basic Turing machine, and basic Turing machine does not contain registers this should be somehow doable. I thought about it for some time now, and I was unable to come up with anything.

**EDIT:** As @JérômeRichard mentioned in comments, all modern processors have registers, and their ISAs are dependent on them. So even memory copying is not possible in them without registers. So here I am going to define a simple architecture for argument purposes.

It is a machine with 2^x addressable units, with each of them having a unique x-bit address. For simplicity, assume there is no concept of virtual memory, and entire address space is mapped directly to physical memory. So, there is no need for requesting memory, process can use its entire x-bit address space freely. Let OS be present outside this address-space and not interfere with user-process.

Also, there is only one user-process running on the machine. But it can multiple threads. All threads share same address space. But they all can independently execute different instructions and on different data. Again, for simplicity, switching of instruction pointer is managed by the OS.

This processor's ISA is capable of reading, writing, copying data on any part of memory given their address. It can also do any arithmetic, logic, bit-manip operations on the data. Let me leave out all other floating-point and vector instructions.

When we have a single thread running, we can fix some global address and store the current function's data like frame pointer and return address and use them. Now, the challenge is to store and restore thread-specific data like these across context switches. Assume this OS does pre-emptive context switches.

Comment: "Registers" is an implementation detail. "Execution context" is the abstraction. The execution context is whatever the OS needs to save now, and restore later in order to suspend and resume execution of the thread. If the OS needs to save and restore the value of some location in memory that points to the top of the current thread's stack, then that memory location is part of the context.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for the "execution context". I will see more about that.

Comment: "every computer is equivalent to basic Turing machine" this is only true if you want to analyse the computability of a problem. Otherwise, this is completely wrong. Analysing the complexity of an algorithm on a Turing machine does not give you the same result than on a computer because computer can do random accesses. The basic operations are not the same. Computers was based on the von Neumann architecture. In fact, they are nowadays based on the modified Harvard architecture. All processors that I am aware of works with registers (it would be crazy to work on DDR-RAM due to its latency).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, complexities are not same. I was just looking for how to do it, aka, doability/computability.

Comment: A context switch is far more than just saving/storing registers. The OS needs to update its data structure, find the next process/thread to execute, en often cause a user to kernel mode switching. User-land context-switching can be implemented by saving/loading register only. That being said. If you store the information generally stored in register into memory, then storing register can be emulated by copying memory. No modern processors can do that without using registers but all processors actually use register so you have to define what the theoretical target processor can do first.